# How to render information from infowindow (google maps)

Tags: javascript

How can I render information from infowindow (google maps) in a separate container from the map on the site? It is necessary to separate the photo.

Comment: are you asking in general or have you tried something specific and its not working?   feel free to add any code you have tried.

Comment: Following stack overflow posting guidelines, you really need to provide _more context_ and _more information_ about what you're trying to do, or you question may be closed by moderators.